# Connecting tiles to make a large image based on text file

Tags: tiles, art, tilemap

If I am building my level from a text file

```
0,0,0,0,0
0,1,0,1,0
0,2,1,0,0
0,0,0,0,0
```

and I want to draw a large image, how do I go about doing that? do I take the image, separate it in tiles (the same size as the other ones) and then add a value to each image

```
0,1,2,3,4,5,6
0,7,8,9,10,11,12
```

or is there another way to do this?
Lets say I want to add a house, or a something like this ship?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Old-school RPG engines like that typically render 2 or more layers of tile maps, f.e.:

- Ground layer (below sprites; roads, floor, etc.)
- Upper layer (above sprites; stuff in front; the upper part of the ship in your image)

This allows sprites to walk behind stuff on the upper layer.
So in your text file, you'd define 2 layers per tilemap, f.e.:

```
// ground layer
1,1,1,1,1,
1,2,2,1,1,
1,2,2,1,1,
1,1,1,1,1,

// upper layer
0,0,0,0,0,
0,3,0,0,3,
0,4,3,0,0,
0,0,0,0,0
```

(I'd recommend using 0 as "no tile")

Comment: very nice, so if this was a house instead of a boat, I would make some of the house tiles on the ground layers, and the rest on the upper layer. And if my house was really large (with 20 different tiles) I would set aside 20 numbers (20-40) as large house tiles

Comment: Yeah. If you have a lot of large graphics of which parts aren't reused, you could consider including arbitrarily sized tiles (although probably with dimensions that are integer multiples of a single tile), at the cost of adding some complexity to the engine/renderer.